# Flutter The minCompileSdk 31 specified in a dependency's AAR metadata is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion android-30

Tags: flutter

while running Flutter debug following error has arisen,

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
     dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
     is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
     Dependency: androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0-beta01.
     AAR metadata file: /home/javeed/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/9d7505e2cdbb28aad564446b7c211aea/work-runtime-2.7.0-beta01/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
The build failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetifier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin device_info...
Exception: The plugin device_info could not be built due to the issue above.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this snippet in the app/build.gradle file above the android {...}

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.6.0' }}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your kind answer, But it has not fixed the issue

Comment: try replace androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0 with androidx.work:work-runtime:2.6.0

Comment: thanks a lot you saved my day, androidx.work:work-runtime:2.6.0 == has fixed the issu

Answer (score 0):

Search for `compileSdkVersion 31` globally and replace it with `compileSdkVersion 30`

Comment: thanks for the answer,  the search in the project show compileSdkVersion 30

Answer (score 0):

Change `compileSdkVersion` to `31` in your `android/app/build.gradle`. You are trying to use a library that requires the compile SDK version to be at least 31. The library seems to be `work-runtime-2.7.0-beta01` so using a lower version, which does not have this requirement, can also be a solution.